# Manipulate setter & getter in PreparedStatement and ResultSet

Tags: java, prepared-statement, ibm-midrange, resultset

following situation:
Our old AS400 DB can't handle UTF8 so I do need to manipulate every select / insert / update. My first thought was: hey, why not override the AS400JDBCPreparedStatement & AS400JDBCResultSet in which I handle set- and getString. Sounds easy, but doesn't work (can't even extend the classes due to constructor visibility).

Does anyone have an idea how to create a simple way to manipulate the resultset.getString(i) and preparedstatement.setString(1, string) methods and let them run through my method manipulateStringBecauseThisDbIsSoOldAndUseless?

Thanks in advance!

@edit:
The actual problem is, that we are losing information of characters like č. Our DB is only able to handle ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I do not have any useful code. I could only provide the string manipulation (more or less only one replace)

Comment: Can you show what happens if you try and use the existing rs.getString() on your DB?

Comment: I would suggest reading your JDBC driver documentation for a property you can set. It shouldn't be something you have to code around.

Comment: What release is the server running, and out of curiosity what model?  To get the model number use the `DSPSYSVAL QMODEL` command.  One way to see the OS release is `DSPOBJD QSYS/QSYS *LIB DETAIL(*SERVICE)` and look at "service level", which should look something like `V5R4M0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try researching for possible JDBC driver properties to configure the character set to send/receive to/from the server.

[JDBC Properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.toolbox.doc/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400JDBCDriver.html) can set set from within code, or appended to datasource configuration if running within a Java EE container (e.g. Websphere).

I don't have AS400 experience but this [list of driver properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahh%2Fjdbcproperties.htm) may be of help. In particular it mentions

> `package ccsid` = Specifies the character encoding to use for the SQL
>    package and any statements sent to the server.
>
> Choices are: "1200" (UCS-2), "13488" (UTF-16)

See also [What character conversion issues must my program deal with?](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/toolbox/faqjdbc.html#faqB3)

Answer (score 0):

Connection connection = null; PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null; ResultSet generatedKeys = null;

```
try {
connection = m_Connection;
preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(qString, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

// ...

int affectedRows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
if (affectedRows == 0) {
    throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no rows affected.");
}

generatedKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
int id = -1;
if (generatedKeys.next()) {
    id = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
    id = -1;
} else {
    throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no generated key obtained.");
}
} finally {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how old your 'AS400' really is, but the IBM i platform has supported UTF8 for quite a while.  Have the people on the IBM side create a test table.  Assuming they are using DDS (they will know what that means), here are UTF8 and UTF16:

```
 A            CHARUTF8      10A         COLHDG('UTF8') 
 A                                      CCSID(1208)    
 A                                      ALWNULL        
 A            CHARUTF16     10G         COLHDG('UTF16')
 A                                      CCSID(1200)    
 A                                      ALWNULL
```

If they are using SQL DDL to define the table, have them try VARGRAPHIC CCSID 1208 for UTF-8 and VARGRAPHIC CCSID 1200 for UTF-16.